# Finding Liapunov Function

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

System

$$\dot{x}=-x+2y^3-2y^4$$
$$\dot{y}=-x-y+xy$$

The Liapunov function of this system could be something like $V=x^m+ay^n$. I am trying to figure out the appropriate values for $m$, $n$, and $a$. I know there is no hard and fast rule to get the Liapunov functions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the linear in x terms in the right-hand side of the system, one can guess that
$$
V(x,y)= \frac12 x^2+\psi(y).
$$
The derivative is
$$
\dot V= x(-x+2y^3-2y^4)+\psi'(y)(-x-y+xy)
$$
$$
=-x^2+x(2y^3-2y^4-\psi'(y)+y\psi'(y))-y\psi'(y).
$$
Let $$2y^3-2y^4-\psi'(y)+y\psi'(y)=0;$$ this gives us
$$
2y^3(1-y)-\psi'(y)(1-y)=0;
$$
hence, $\psi'(y)=2y^3$, $\psi(y)=\frac12 y^4$ and $V(x,y)=\frac12 x^2+\frac12 y^4$.